# What is the memory stored in bfReserved1 reserved for?

Tags: c, bmp

I've been reading up on BMP files, specifically BITMAPFILEHEADERS on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx, and was wondering what bfReserved1 was reserved for

Comment: Nothing special. It can be any seemingly random value. It's reserved for future expansion and should simply not be read or written by you.

Comment: Then a little nitpicking on your "question", or rather how you asked it. The title should be a short *summary* of the problem, and the actual question should be in the body. If you haven't done it yet then please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to check out some highly voted questions to use as reference for your own future questions.

Comment: It is lost in the fog of time.  These fields were already reserved back in 1990 when the structure was first defined.  So likely were intended for future expansion.  That never happened, BITMAPV4HEADER was next and was widely ignored.  Move on with your life, nothing to see here.

Comment: @HansPassant well that kinda does answer my questions, so thank you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll try to improve the style of my questions, I keep visiting this site on and off, but I'll probably be using it on a more regular basis from now on so I'll definetly read up on the link you sent!